# Audium spectrum as particel emitter - After Effects

Tags: after-effects

I'm playing around with audio reaction in After Effects and I'm trying to create an audio spectrum, that acts as a particle emitter. So the bars not only jump up when that frequency is present, but also emit an amount of particles representing the amount that frequency is present.

Now my question: How do I link my audio spectrum with my particle generator (I do own the Trapcode Particular suite)

Thanks, nxt191 aka Marc

Comment: Hi user3235390 :) In order to get a solid answer, please add a screenshot to clarify what exactly do you want to achieve. Something like: https://vimeo.com/24488104 ? Maybe you want to start with the tour: http://video.stackexchange.com/tour to get your first badge ;) Anyway, enjoy video.se!